# Connect web app with cross subscription Vnet to Vnet connect to virtual machine

Tags: azure, networking, azure-virtual-network

Currently I have a web app deployed on an Azure subscription and a VM deployed on another subscription.

I would like to connect both the web app and the VM to the same virtual network. I've set up a virtual network on the web app subscription with a virtual network gateway. I've also set up a virtual network on the VM subscription with a corresponding virtual network gateway.

However, after establishing the Vnet to Vnet connection between the two gateways, my app is unable to connect to the VM using the internal ip of the VM. Furthermore, the connection status between the two gateways occasionally show up as "unknown".

Does anyone know what's going wrong here? Is there some better way I can connect a web app with a VM on another Azure subscription?

Edit:
The app is deployed as a web service.

Thanks.

Comment: why don't you treat your VM as a local machine which can be added to the vnet of your Web App directly?

Comment: Is the webapp deployed in a VM as well, or are you using App Services (and hence they're deployed in a public web farm)?  The answer will be different depending on this.